# How to check if a group exists and add if it doesn't in Linux Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

this is a summary of what i want my code to do:

```
if (group exists)
then

  (add user to group)

else

  (create group)

  (add user to group)

fi
```

I am using the Ubuntu virtual machine but all of the results i have found on similar sites do not work.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This script may help you:

```
   read -p "enter group name: " group
   if grep -q $group /etc/group
    then
         echo "group exists"
    else
         echo "group does not exist"
    fi
```

Comment: This is pretty much what i started with that didnt work.. i will attach screenshots of the code and what happens when it runs    *edit* i cant attach pictures *edit*

Comment: I think `if grep -q "^${group}:" /etc/group` is much safer.

Comment: My shell script stopped when run this statements, Better follow @andiba answer.

Comment: mm, it's just because of the `read`. You can replace first line with `group=lol`

Comment: This should work for local groups but doesn't work if groups are provided by LDAP.

Comment: to use on the command line instead of in a script, remove the "-q".

Answer (score 108):

The `grep` statement in the solution of [rups](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2481010/rups) has some flaws:

E.g. `grepping` for a group `admin` may return `true` ("group exists") when there is a group `lpadmin`.

Either fix the `grep`-query

```
grep -q -E "^admin:" /etc/group
```

or use

```sh
if [ $(getent group admin) ]; then
  echo "group exists."
else
  echo "group does not exist."
fi
```

Comment: You can chain getent to create the group if it doesn't exist thusly:
`getent group admin || groupadd [options] admin`
You can further chain that with `&& useradd -G admin someuser` to make a one-liner that should create the group if needed and then add the user to it.

Comment: You don't need `-E` in `grep` for that regex.

Comment: The use of getent seems like the most direct answer to the question.  It seems to avoid text-parsing corner cases and just returns a 0 or 2 exit code which is what we should be after in a function anyway.

Comment: this is better written as simply `if getent group admin`, no need to put it in `test`

Answer (score 28):

Grepping /etc/group works, but only on a machine where /etc/nsswitch.conf has:

```
group: files
```

meaning that only /etc/group is consulted when determining available groups. Use either of these (by name or by gid):

```
getent group <groupname>
getent group <groupid>
```

for a more generic solution, checking the exit status: 0 means "exists", non-zero means "does not exist".  For example, to check to see if group 'postgres' exists, and create it if it does not (assuming bash shell, running as a user able to create new groups) run:

```
/usr/bin/getent group postgres 2>&1 > /dev/null || /usr/sbin/groupadd postgres
```

Comment: `getent` isn't available on macOS (and possibly all BSD) so it's not exactly more generic -- but it might be ok if you fall back to grep: `getent group postgres || grep -q postgres /etc/group`

Answer (score 10):

I've found it more useful, to compose andiba's solution into a proper function:

```bash
function grpexists {
    if [ $(getent group $1) ]; then
      echo "group $1 exists."
    else
      echo "group $1 does not exist."
    fi
}
```

This can for e.g be invoked into your environment by including this function in your `/etc/bash.bashrc*`, such that you can then check for the existence of a group, using the following spell:

```
grpexists group_name
```

Which should then return one of:

> group group_name exists.

or

> group group_name does not exist.

Answer (score 9):

**Single line:**
$getent group <-groupname-> || groupadd <-groupname->

Answer (score 4):

Here are 3 commands which should work:

```
group=sudo
grep -qw ^$group /etc/group || groupadd $group
usermod -aG $group $USER
```

Or one, when you use `-f`/`--force` (exit successfully if the group already exists):

```
groupadd -f mygroup && usermod -aG mygroup $USER
```

Comment: For completeness, if the group fails to be added, there should be some error handling. E.g., ```sudo groupadd -f '' && echo "success" || echo "fail"```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ groupadd --help
Usage: groupadd [options] GROUP

Options:
  -f, --force                   exit successfully if the group already exists,
                                and cancel -g if the GID is already used
```

So you can do simply:

```
groupadd -f some_new_grp
```

Answer (score 0):

Geeks great solutions and guidance, thanks for sharing here are my 2 cents to make our lives simpler or lazier :-) I could use to complement an useradd script I have to add several users at once. I'm wondering how it would look like inside a for 
 in loop for several groups: group1, group2, group3...group6
Then useradd to the system something like this?

`for g in $( cat fewgroups.txt ); do
         groupadd $g 
         echo "Group:" $g "Exist not added moving on"
        else
         echo "Group:" $g "added successfully!"
         # Then create the users
      for u in $( cat 100sofusers.txt ); do
        useradd -m -g group1 -G group2,wheel -d /home/$u  -c "Just anothe SiFiGeek" -s /bin/bash $u
         echo "userID:" $u "added successfully!"
         echo $u:$randompw | chpasswd
         echo "Password for userID:" $u "changed successfully"
      done`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that an existing USER is added to the GROUP then this flow

```
if (group exists)
then
  (add user to group)
else
  (create group)
  (add user to group)
fi
```

can be simplified to:

```
if (group exists)
then
   # do nothing
else
  (create group)

fi
(add user to group)
```

`then ... # do nothing` can be removed and condition changed to `if NOT exists` to simplify the flow further

```
if (group NOT exists)
then
  (create group)
fi
(add user to group)
```

There is no need to check `if (group NOT exists)` if you may attempt to create a group and have no problem if it already exists. Thus the whole flow can be simplified to:

```
(create group) AND (add user to group)
```

[how to do that in code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55172750)